# Directory size limit

Tags: linux, files

In Linux, it's possible to limit the size of a partition, for example with quota. But does a way to limit directory size exist?
For example, I have a directory, let say `/mnt/foo/bar`, which is not a partition(e.g. not in `df` result). Is it possible?
No `mkfs` possible on this directory.

Answer (score 8):

Not directly, you could create a file of the size that you want to limit the directory to and then mount it using a loop mount into the tree.

- Create a file to use as a filesystem e.g.

  - `fallocate -l 100M disk.img` ( this isn't always compatible with an underlying FS.)
  - `dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img count=512k`
- create a filesystem on the disk image

  - `mkfs disk.img`
- mount the image

  - `mount -o loop disk.img /path/to/mount/point` (optionally you can enable quotas too)

Comment: Don't meet my requirements.

Comment: @totomaster nothing meets your requirements this is just a work arund.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for would be a nice feature, but I am not aware of any file system with such a feature. The best approximation without adding more file systems would be to use quotas, which limit storage space per user (or group).

One problem with doing it per directory is that the semantics are not going to be obvious, once you consider the possibility that a file may be hardlinked.

Consider the following sequence of events:

- Administrator configure a system with 1GB quota per home directory
- `user1` run a program, which creates a logfile in `~user1`
- When the logfile is 1MB large `user2` creates a hardlink in `~user2`
- `user2` adds 900MB of other files to `~user2`
- `user1` appends 900MB of data to the logfile
- `user1` deletes the logfile from `~user1`

There is not any one single of the above operations, you would expect to fail due to quota limits. Yet the outcome is that `user2` is way above quota in the end.